# CSS Flip effect fine tuning

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

So, I was trying to create flip effect with css and here I am... ***fiddle link***: https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/db11mmut/

I have 2 sides, front and back side. Issue is, back side is hidden until front side is rotated for 180deg. I would like to avoid that and make back side partially visible during rotation of front side, in order to make fine flip effect.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

**Code:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.container:hover .el{ 
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.el {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background: #eee;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.front {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: lightgreen;
  backgace-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
  backgace-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">
    <div class="front">
      Front Side
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Back Side
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove `transform: rotateY(0deg);` and the `z-index` from the front class, here is a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/db11mmut/2/